# Create Table using data.frame R Database using ODBCConnect TERADATA FASTLOAD

Tags: r, dataframe, odbc

I am using ODBC and **R** to connect to a Database (Teradata), this works for the connection.  I have a data.frame with 2 columns/variables.

Is there a way to say: (Create table Name As Select * from data.frame)

Basically I want to import the data.frame into a table.

This works:

```
sqlSave(con, datafile, tablename = "TABLE.NAME", rownames = FALSE, append = TRUE, fast = TRUE)
```

So this works, but it is a slow process, is there anyway to implement FastLoad/TPump, or anything like that? When I have larger files?

Please show an example.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
sessions 2;
errlimit 25;
logon tdpid/ID,PASSWORD;

CREATE TEST_FAST_UPLOAD (
       CUST_KEY INTEGER,
       HOUSEHOLD_KEY INTEGER ) ;

set record TEXT;

define
       CUST_KEY( integer,
       HOUSEHOLD_KEY( integer,
       )

file=insert.input;

show;

begin loading TEST_FAST_UPLOAD errorfiles TEST_FAST_UPLOAD_ERR;

insert into TEST_FAST_UPLOAD(
       :CUST_KEY,
       :HOUSEHOLD_KEY
);

end loading;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually just worked through this myself.  Here's how I did it:

1. Save the data.frame to a fixed width file using write.fwf() from the gdata package.  For example `write.fwf(x = dataFrame, file = "dataFile.txt", sep = "", colnames = FALSE, width = c(20, 20))`.
2. Create the fast load script as a txt file, e.g. fastLoadExampleScript.txt.  If you need help with this I recommend starting with http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_13_10/index.html#page/Load_and_Unload_Utilities/B035_2411_020A/2411Ch01.03.24.html.  A few important notes: (a) when using write.fwf with sep = "" as I did, you won't need any of the delim or newlinechar, (b) use SET RECORD TEXT and make sure the widths specified in the function should match those in the DEFINE portion of the fast load script.
3. First setwd() to the directory containing dataFile.txt and fastLoadExampleScript.txt.  Then run `shell("fastload < fastLoadExampleScript.txt")`.

EDIT: 
Regarding the script, most of it looks good except the DEFINE portion, which I think should be

```
define
       CUST_KEY(char(20)),
       HOUSEHOLD_KEY(char(20))
```

Comment: Awesome, let me take a look, thanks for all the time and feedback, sharing is great!

Comment: why the fixed width format helps ? just trying to understand ?

Comment: When trying to use variable length columns, I could never get it to work.  It may be possible, but I couldn't figure it out.  Keep in mind that the database table can still have any data type.

Comment: so I take it I need to download the teradata utility tools ? and install them on my system ?

Comment: If I edit my post, do you mind looking at the loadingscript.txt to make sure I did it right ?  I want to upload 2 integer columns.

Comment: Please take a look, let me know what you think, thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer regarding the script.  As for the utility tools, I'm not entirely sure.  The Teradata install we used at work included a bunch of different things.